# Issues Iterating Through List of Strings

Tags: python

My python code is not compiling correctly. Here is the question:
Return the number of sets in the provided Set hand.

```
Parameters:
    cards (list(str)) a list of twelve cards as 4-bit integers in
    base 3 as strings, such as ["1022", "1122", ..., "1020"].
Returns:
    (int) The number of sets in the hand.
Raises:
    ValueError: if the list does not contain a valid Set hand, meaning
        - there are not exactly 12 cards,
        - the cards are not all unique,
        - one or more cards does not have exactly 4 digits, or
        - one or more cards has a character other than 0, 1, or 2.
```

Here is my code:

```py
def count_sets(cards):
 num_sets = len(cards)
    for i in range(num_sets):
        for j in range(num_sets):
            cards_test = cards[i]
            for m in range(len(cards_test)):
                if num_sets != 12:
                    raise ValueError("there are not exactly 12 cards,")
                elif i != j:
                    if cards_test == cards[j]:
                        raise ValueError("the cards are not all unique,")
                elif len(cards_test) != 4:
                    raise ValueError("one or more cards does not have exactly 4 digits, or")
                elif cards_test[m] != 0 or cards_test[m] != 1 or cards_test[m] != 2: #----the problem is here
                    raise ValueError("one or more cards has a character other than 0, 1, or 2.")
                else:
                    return num_sets
    
print(count_sets(["1111", "2222", "1212", "1222", "1112", "0011", "0022", "2211", "1010", "0000", "1221", "0220"]))
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: What steps have you taken to try to debug your code? What are the error messages? At which lines? Why is there a nested `for` loop?

Comment: It will return this     raise ValueError("one or more cards has a character other than 0, 1, or 2.")

ValueError: one or more cards has a character other than 0, 1, or 2." But I need to to not return a ValueError

Comment: The problem is at the line with the comment `#----the problem is here` @AAAlex123

Comment: @acme_2020 your conditions `cards_test[m] != 0 or cards_test[m] != 1 or cards_test[m] != 2` are wrong, you raise the exception when the checked number is different from 0 or 1 or 2, so it will raise each time

Comment: @CarloZanocco how would I change it? I tried using cards_test[m] not in {0, 1, 2} but I think that is the same thing as before, as it didnt work

Comment: try to replace `or` with `and` otherwise you can do `cards_test[m] not in [0, 1, 2]`

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```py
elif cards_test[m] != 0 or cards_test[m] != 1 or cards_test[m] != 2:
```

It should be:

```py
elif cards_test[m] != 0 and cards_test[m] != 1 and cards_test[m] != 2:
```

meaning if `cards_test[m]` is not 0 and it's not 1 and it's not 2, then raise Error.

A better way to write this is the following:

```py
elif not cards_test[m] in "012":
```